# ASP.NET Permission Frameworks?

Tags: asp.net, t-sql, frameworks, permissions, roleprovider

### **Problem**

ASP.NET has no concept of associating permissions to roles.

### My app

Current web application is using custom user membership and role providers.  The app has 4 roles: **superuser**, **admin**, **principal**, and **teacher**.  When the user logs in, they are redirected to their appropriate UI.  For example, admins are redirected to admin interface, teachers are redirected to teacher interface.  Each interface has its own master page and aspx pages.  A new requirement is that teachers are no longer allowed to view specific information or *do* specific functions.  Information could be a field or a row in a gridview control, it could be functional as well (e.g. not able to click on a link to open a popup window, but still be able to see the link's text).  Other roles also have need of specific "permission" requirements, but completely different than the teachers ones.

### **Proposed Solution**

Create a database table to centralize mapping of permissionsToRoles like so:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[PermissionToRole](
    [PermissionID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL primary key,
    [Role] int NOT NULL,
    [Control] [varchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [ControlType] [varchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [Function] [varchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [Read] [bit] NULL,
    [Write] [bit] NULL,
    [Execute] [bit] NULL,
    [Delete] [bit] NULL
)
```

> Using the link example above we would get something like:  "teacher",
>   "labelName", "asp:label", "click", 1, 0, 0, 0 (can read the link but
>   not "execute" the click)

The plan is to be able to do a few things:

1. Use permissions to consolidate multiple aspx and logic into a single page (aspx).  To reduce maintenance every time a new role is needed.
2. Control at a all levels (tab -> control) a roles' aka groups' permissions.  E.g. use this table to control visibility of controls at every level (tab, page, control).  As well as individual functionality (e.g. click on a link control)
3. Control what data is returned to the UI and what CRUD operations are allowed.

**Are there frameworks out there for ASP.NET that can do this already?**  I'm pretty sure Content Management Systems (CMS) can do this, but this app will not use a CMS :).  I really want to avoid reinventing the wheel.

Thanks!

Comment: ASP.NET has no concept of user/group permissions? So what are Membership and Role providers used for? You can provide ACLs in the web.config to restrict locations (pages, folders).

Comment: @Luis - I updated my question.  I don't see how ACLs are relevant here.  Care to elaborate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Decided on trying [NetSqlAzMan](http://netsqlazman.codeplex.com/) because:

- Not COM and *IS* .NET 4
- RDBMS for Data Store
- AOP (Aspect Oriented Programming) (Can use attributes instead of massive if/else checks)
- Lously coupled
- Handles Permissions to Roles scenarios
- Free

Answer (score 2):

Look at [AzMan](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff649313.aspx). I have a feeling that it's what you seek.

With AzMan you define *operations* and check if user authorized to do an *operation* in code. You can then define which roles allowed to do which operations and assign roles to users -- because you're checking against operations, not roles, no code changes will be necessary if you want to introduce a new role or reassign operations between roles.

Comment: @subt13 Well, it seems you can't use it under partial trust. But if you don't have that limitation, it's a good thing to try. (There's one 'perk' though: when it reads an xml store it locks the file exclusively which can cause problems. But the latest version of the library can use an SQL server as a storage so it's avoidable.)

Comment: So far your solution is on target.  Still hoping for alternative frameworks though.

Answer (score 0):

In truth, the [ASP.net membership controls](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh26yfzy.aspx) ought to be able to do what you want.  Setting up a database with the appropriate schema allows you to use a huge suite of methods and objects to control user access.  Like Luis mentions, you can access control pages and folders to certain roles, but if you want to lock out individual functions based on a user's role, you can use the [`IsUserInRole()` method.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4z6b5d42.aspx)

There isn't a whole lot of point in reinventing the wheel if you can use a built-in, well-tested process.

Comment: I think you are confusing roles or groups with permissions.  Also, access control to physical pages is irrelevant to my question.  IsUserInRole method is limited to checking if a user is in single role.  Obviously, I need more that that.  For one, I don't feel like cluttering up my code and markup with IsUserInRole checks.  Besides would need something like IsRoleInPermissions or IsUserInRoleInPermissions :).

Comment: Am I?  The way I understand your request, you have a set of roles, a set of permissions, and there's a many-to-many relationship between the two.  But in no case can a user be a member of a role and not have that role's permissions.  If a user's role can't perform the task represented by a page, the role shouldn't have access to the page.  Similarly, if a user can't perform an action on a page he has access to, the role should be checked and disallowed.  If you really want to break it down another level, you could add the relevant Permission and PermissionToRole tables/method calls yourself.

Comment: I think this explains (better than I can) the reason I don't agree with your solution: http://lostechies.com/derickbailey/2011/05/24/dont-do-role-based-authorization-checks-do-activity-based-checks/

Comment: I agree and wrote about it here:  http://granadacoder.wordpress.com/2010/12/01/rant-hard-coded-security-roles/  .  I loathe role based security.